Restore committed changes to Azure Databricks Git after abandoned pull request
I want to restore the committed changes (before and after view) in my branch. As this pull request was abandoned in Azure DevOps, then the branch was not merged. Therefore, the modified notebooks still exist but not the commits.
How can I retrieve again these changes as I cannot see them to send them again when I require it?

The branch exists.
The notebooks with changes exist.



Based on your description, you need to get the commit history of the repo.
In Azure Databricks, you can edit the files in workspace and use the version history to check the commit changes in Azure Databricks. Then you can restore the version based on your requirement.
For example:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Git version control for notebooks (legacy)
On the other hand, you can navigate to Azure DevOps Repo and check the commits in Azure Repos -> Commits.
If you need to restore the changed commit, you can open the target commit and use the Revert option.

Then you can create pull request to revert the branch to previous commit.
Finally, you can pull the changes in Azure Databricks to restore the changed commits.
For example:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Revert from a recent revision from the web portal
